# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /mytesting/< on this server. ERROR

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to figure our what causing the error on my simple login localhost program.

My base_url = http://localhost/MYTESTING

I have this on my `loginpage.php` controller

```
public function login(){

    $data['title'] = "TEST LOGIN";

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');


    $this->load->view("loginheaderTest.php",$data);
    $this->load->view("loginpage.php",$data);
    $this->load->view("footerTest.php",$data);


    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $data['authenticate'] = $this->AuthenticationTest->authenticate_acount($username,$password);

            if(!empty($data['authenticate']))
            {
              echo"<script>
                alert('Success');
                </script>
                ";  
            }
            else
            {
                echo"<script>
                alert('Invalid Username or Password');
                </script>
                ";
            }
    }

}
```

and I have this on my model

```
    public function authenticate_account($username,$password){

    $this->db->select("username");
    $this->db->from("accounts");
    $this->db->where("username",$username);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
```

and this on my view :

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <form action = "<?base_url();?>" method = "POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                           </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>

                        <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value = "Login" name = "login">                     
                </fieldset> 
            </form>             
        </div>
```

I am pretty sure I am correct on my configurations in my database config when I visit localhost/mytesting and click login the error occurs.

Comment: 403 is an apache error. Your PHP code is irrelevant, you never get to run the code.

Comment: You seem to be using the password as entered by the user in your where clause. Should you not be encrypting / hashing the password to match how it is stored in the db? I'm not a code igniter user, but I'm not sure the best way to authenticate a user is to search a database for a matching password.

Comment: Is this a new server setup?

Comment: no i have a previous project named my pms

Comment: Can you access any pages in the new project?

Comment: i can access my default controller, the loginpage, but when I type a username and password and click login the error occurs even if the username and password is wrong

Comment: Does base_url() function actually echo anything? If it only returns a value and doesn't echo then your forms action will be empty.

Comment: Looking at the code igniter docs, base_url() returns the base url and doesn't echo it. As you are using short tags, try <?= base_url(); ?> in your forms method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your server config allow the use of PHP short tags?

```
You don't have permission to access /mytesting/< on this server.
```

It looks as though your form action is pointing towards "/mytesting/<" and the following "?" is being removed from the error message, as it's interpreted as a query string.

Change this:

```
<form action = "<?base_url();?>" method = "POST">
```

To this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" method="POST">
```

Or enable PHP short tags in your php.ini or .htaccess.

Comment: As per my comment, it looks like base_url() only returns and doesn't echo. The correct short tag would therefore be <?= base_url() ?>

Comment: Both your comment, and the existing code would work, if short tags were enabled. An empty form action causes the form to be submitted back to the exact same url it was submitted from, so in this case, a blank action wouldn't cause this error. The problem is that the form action here is the literal string "<?base_url();?>", not the interpreted PHP output string containing the base url. Even a blank or missing action attribute would solve this problem.

Comment: Assuming the login code was in the same controller.

Comment: my short tags is enabled but i cant use <?base_url();?> only <?=base_url()?>